# Insert & Update SQL Table from XML file data using VB.NET 2010

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I have been researching and writing/re-writing a program to do this task for a week now. I need some collaboration on this to maybe bring up something I haven't though of before. Specifically, we have an auto-generated XML file sent to us daily with ~70k records (~75MB in size.) I was asked to make a table on one of the servers (SQL) which contains this information so that it can queried. Also, this program must Update existing records (if data has changed) and Insert new records DAILY. **Records must not be deleted from the db**

Here is the list of methods I have attempted (so far) and reasons they did not work.

1. SQLXMLBulkLoad - This worked excellent for importing the data.
   However, the limitation of the Bulk Load class is that it can not
   Update and/or Insert. Time for a re-write.
2. SQL OpenRowSet (using SQLCommand, etc.) - This does not work
       because the server, program, and XML file will all 3 be on different
       computers. These devices CAN be configured to allow each other
       access to the file (specifically the server), however this method
       was deemed "Not realistic, too much overhead" Time for a re-write.
3. DataSet Merge, then TableAdapter.Update - This method intitially
       seemed like it would definitely work. The idea is simple, use
       DataSet.XMLRead() method to put the XML data into a table in the
       dataset, then just add the SQL table to the dataset (Using
       SQLCommand, etc.), merge the two tables, and then use Table Adapter
       to Update/Insert the table into the existing SQL table. This method
       seems not to work because the XML file has two nodes (columns) which
       contains dates. Unfortunately, there is not a uniform Date datatype
       between SQL and XML. I even attempted changing all of the date
       formats from the XML file to the DateTime SQL format, which worked,
       but still deemed a datatype mismatch exception upon running.

At this point, I am out of ideas. This seems to be a task that has surely been done before. I am not necessarily looking for someone to write this code for me (I am fully capable of this), I just need some collaboration on the topic.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar with database imports received in XML format, and all I do is pass the XML directly to a stored procedure and then shred the XML using XQuery and OPENXML.

Both of those technologies allow you to query XML in SQL as if it was a table in your database.  Taking that approach, you can just pass your XML to a script or stored procedure, query it in SQL, and insert the results wherever you need them.  Anecdotally, [OPENXML is better for processing large XML files](http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/general/2010/questions/sqlserver-quiz-general-2010-jacob-sebastian-openxml-or-xquery-when-and-why.aspx), but you could try both and see how they work for you.  Below is an example using OPENXML and a simple merge statement.

```
create procedure ImportXml
(
    @importXml xml
)
as
--with OPENXML you have to prepare the document before you use it
--this is unecessary with XQuery
DECLARE @idoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @importXml;

--this is just a typical Merge statement that will update data if it exists
--and insert it if it does not
merge NormalDataTable
using
(
     --here is where you are querying the XML document directly.  You can 
     --see, it works just like a SQL statement, with a special syntax for
     --specifying where to get data out of the XML document and how to map
     --it to a table structure
     select *
     from openxml(@idoc, '/Root/Element')
     with
     (
         ElementID int '@ElementID',
         ElementValueName varchar(50) '@ElementValueName'
     ) 
) source
on NormalDataTable.ElementID = source.ElementID
when not matched then
    insert ...
when matched then
    update ...

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on this? I'll do some Googling as well.

Comment: @jpm0004 Added some more explanatory text.  If you need help with XQuery examples, can do that too, but they are pretty easy to find.

Comment: @ Bert Evans, I like this idea. But I foresee having problems implementing it just as I had implementing OPENROWSET directly from the SQL Server. See Method 2 in the OP. I may just need to have a meeting to try and push through the idea of changing server permission so it can access the file.

Comment: You didn't mention what size of XML files you were loading with this method. Nor does the link you cited. To caution future readers : `OPENXML` should NOT be considered an option for "large" XML files, where "large" is relative to the memory on your machine. In fact it should be considered deprecated after SQL Server 2005 which added a native XML data type. `sp_xml_preparedocument` is dangerous because it loads the entire XML document into memory (using RAM several times the file size) and hence unsuitable for arbitrarily large files on a server. Large files call for a streamed loading design.